# how to convert a Image to video using avconv

Tags: php, ubuntu, libavcodec, avcodec

i want to create a video from a image i used following code

```
shell_exec("avconv -f image2 -r 50 testimage.jpg output.mpg");
```

But when i trying  to playing output video it shows **stream contains no data**

Comment: Did you try the 'shell commend' directly? what was your results?

Comment: @ome i got output.mpg but when i trying to play that it shows  stream contains no data

Comment: `avconv -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi` <- from the docs... maybe it requires the `-s` parameter. Still trying to figure out what `-s` does. Ignore if you already tried it.

Comment: @ShyamK thanks i got it, 1 more problem duration is very less then how can i increase duration of play back

Comment: `-r 20` reduce the frame rate?

Comment: @ShyamK I want to increase Play back Duration

Comment: Also do post an answer to your question :)

Comment: `-t duration` Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration. duration may be a number in seconds, or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form

Comment: @ShyamK i want to duration of time 10secs

Comment: try something like `-t 00:00:10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [avconv manual](https://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion) says

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> **avconv -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi**
>
> The syntax foo-%03d.jpeg specifies to use a decimal number composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number.

There is a `-s WxH` in that line which is missing from your code. Maybe that is the cause. 
`-s WxH` is used to specify the size of the video, W - width and H - height. Here is a [list of formats supported](https://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html#Video-Options)

On increasing the playback time, again the manual says

> **`-t duration (output)`**
>
> Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration. duration may be a number in seconds, or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form.